# How to get link and page information of new opened tab in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

i was trying to scrape [this](https://www.tracksellers.com/) website. the process i followed was search a user click the first user and get information about him/her. after i clicked the user it is opening a new tab, so how can i get the information in the newly opened tab.

[image: this is the first page where i search a user and click]
[image: this is the second page that i get when i click each user]

the code that i have written so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/XXX/chromewebdriver/chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.tracksellers.com/')

search = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='desktop-seller-search']")))

search.click()

word = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='d-seller-autocomplete']")))

word.send_keys('james')

searchdiv = word = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='d-seller-autocomplete-box']")))

searchresult = searchdiv.find_element_by_id('list')
searchresult = searchresult.find_elements_by_tag_name('li')

searchresult[0].click()

# the above code search's for a user and click on the first user 

# next steps i tried
driver.window_handles

# gives me the below output
['CDwindow-70F83E4DCEB9D746B96FD9D965FC1BF7',
 'CDwindow-87428C4E8AF3614CFE2C461A0B3AE765']

# trying to get the current tab by using this code, but it gives only the first tab
driver.current_window_handle

# output
'CDwindow-70F83E4DCEB9D746B96FD9D965FC1BF7'
```

How can i switch from one tab to another tab and access tags and other things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's in a new tab so you would need to switch the driver focus to the newly opened tab :

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

You need to write this code right after the click on first page.

Answer (score 0):

```
  maintab = driver.current_window_handle




  for handle in driver.window_handles:
            if handle != main_page:
              othertab = handle

 driver.switch_to.window(othertab)
```

After this you can use your code on tab2
Also ,with this code you can switch back to your main tab using

```
 driver.switch_to.window(maintab)
```

again